# show that function is odd

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Consider a function $f \in C([-1,1],\mathbb{R})$ and suppose that

$$\int_{-1}^{1} f(t)t^{2n}dt=0$$

for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$. I want to show that under this assumption the function $f$ has to be odd, that is $f(x)=-f(-x)$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$.

Let $A$ denote the set $span\{t^{2n}:n \in \mathbb{N_0}\}$, then $a \in A$ is of the form $\sum_{i=0}^{k} \alpha_i t^{2i}, \alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}$. The set $A$ is a linear space and obviously closed under multiplication, so it becomes an algebra satisfying the conditions of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem. Every $f \in C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ can therefore be uniformly approximated by elements of $A$.

How can I proceed? Is it useful to do he same approximation argument for $g \in C([-1,0],\mathbb{R})$ and then approximate $f$ by sums of two functions? How do I get from $a(t)2^n$ even to $f$ odd? I suppose I have to exchange the integral and the limit process by uniform converge, however, I don't know how to put the things together :S A hint would be great, merci!

Comment: Write $f = g + h$ with $g$ even and $h$ odd. Try to relate that to the Stone-Weierstrass argument.

Comment: You might apply Stone-Weierstrass on $[-1,1]$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $f= f_e + f_o,$ where $f_e(x) = (f(x) + f(-x))/2, f_o(x) = (f(x) - f(-x))/2.$ Note that $f_e$ is even, $f_o$ is odd. Since $f_o$ is odd, we have

$$\int_{-1}^1 f_o(t)t^{2n}\, dt = 0$$

for all $n.$ Our hypothesis then implies

$$\int_{-1}^1 f_e(t)t^{2n}\, dt = 0$$

for all $n.$ But note

$$\int_{-1}^1 f_e(t)t^{2n}\, dt = 2\int_{0}^1 f_e(t)t^{2n}\, dt.$$

A simple argument, using Weierstrass, shows polynomials in $t^2$ are dense in $C([0,1]).$ Thus $\int_{0}^1f_ep = 0$ for any such polynomial $p,$ which implies $f_e\equiv 0$ on $[0,1],$ hence on $[-1,1].$ Thus $f=f_0,$ i.e., $f$ is odd.

Comment: I think you want a different lower limit in your last integral.

Comment: Indeed I did. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you let $B=\text{span}\,\{t^{2n+1}:\ n\in\mathbb N_0\}$, then $\overline A$ and $\overline B$ are two orthogonal subspaces that span $L^2[-1,1]$. As $f$ is orthogonal to $B$ it should lie in $A$. So $f$ is an $L^2$-limit of linear combinations of odd powers of $t$.